# Delete spaces in dictionary values python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm reading the data from an outsource. The data has "Name" and "Value with warnings" so I put those in a dictionary in a manner as

```
d[data[i:i+6]] = data[i+8:i+17], data[i+25:i+36]
```

Thus at the end I have my dict as;

```
{'GPT-P ': ('169      ', 'H          '), 'GOT-P ': ('47       ', '           '), .....
```

As seen above both keys and values might have unnecessary spaces.
I was able to overcome spaces in keys with;

```
d = {x.replace(' ',''): v
     for x, v in d.items()}
```

but can't seem to manage similar for values. I tried using `d.values()` but it trims the key name and also works only for 1 of the values.

Can you help me understand how I can remove space for several ***values*** (2 values in this particular case) and end up with something like;

```
{'GPT-P': ('169', 'H'), 'GOT-P ': ('47', ''), .....
```

Thanks. Stay safe and healthy

Comment: Do you want to DELETE spaces so that `'     1    2    3    '` becomes `'123'` or strip spaces so that `'     1    2    3    '` becomes `'1    2    3'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to do the space replacement in your `v` values also but
it seems that in your case the values in your dictionary are **tuples**.

I guess you will want to remove spaces in all elements of each tuple so you will need a second iteration here. You can do something like this:

```
d = {'GPT-P ': ('169      ', 'H          '), 'GOT-P ': ('47       ', '           ')}

{x.replace(' ', ''): tuple(w.replace(' ', '') for w in v) for x, v in d.items()}
```

Which returns:

```
{'GPT-P': ('169', 'H'), 'GOT-P': ('47', '')}
```

Notice that there is list (or tuple) comprehension `tuple(w.replace(' ', '') for w in v)` within the dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
DoT={'GPT-P ': ('169      ', 'H          '), 'GOT-P ': ('47       ', '           ')}
```

Since you have tuples of strings as your values, you need to apply `.strip()` to each string in the tuple:

```
>>> tuple(e.strip() for e in ('47       ', '           '))
('47', '')
```

Apply that to each key, value in a dict comprehension and there you are:

```
>>> {k.strip():tuple(e.strip() for e in t) for k,t in DoT.items()}
{'GPT-P': ('169', 'H'), 'GOT-P': ('47', '')}
```

---

You use `.replace(' ','')` in your attempt. That will replace ALL spaces:

```
>>> '     1    2    3    '.replace(' ','')
'123'
```

It is more typical to use one of the `.strips()`:

```
>>> '     1    2    3    '.strip()
'1    2    3'
>>> '     1    2    3    '.lstrip()
'1    2    3    '
>>> '     1    2    3    '.rstrip()
'     1    2    3'
```

You can use `.replace` or any of the `.strips()` in the comprehensions that I used above.